# How to prepare a wall with drywall for painting after wallpaper removal

Tags: drywall, painting

I have removed wallpaper on drywall. It only took 10 minutes to remove, however, the wall was primed as instructed to make removal easier.  I am now trying to remove paste residue and am damaging the wall while doing so.  Those areas are rough. There is a product called Gardz that you place on the wall to hold in the paste. Will this do the trick.  I am also thinking of having two walls skim coated before painting. The other two walls are horse hair plaster and will be skim coated.  Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

Skim coat is more reliable than magic paint, but no direct experience with that particular flavor of magic paint, just seen lots of problems in general with magic paint and wallpaper residue.

The counterintuitive (at first) fastest (and thus cheapest when labor is a cost, however you count that cost) approach that's 100% reliable is to rock over it (you can use the thin stuff), or rip and replace the rock. Skim coating seems like it's less drastic, but can actually be a lot slower.

Comment: Is the GARDZ the same as magic paint?